# Why does Apache execute php file on calling file without extension

Tags: php, apache, apache2

Today I found a strange thing on my server.
I created a php file (test.php) and wrote some php codes inside it. then I call it using

```
http://127.0.0.1/test
```

and the "test.php" executed ! How does it understand to run test.php when there is no .php ?
there is no htaccess file on my root directory to tell the apache do that.
I guess it may causes security problem. How can I prevent it ?

My OS is ubuntu and the web server is Apache2.

Comment: How does that cause a security problem? If someone can access example.com/test they can just as well access example.com/test.php.

Answer (score 7):

This happens because of MultiViews (it's enabled somewhere in the "Options" for that directory).

Have a look here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html#negotiation for details on how it works.

Comment: This is indeed the reason.

Answer (score 3):

Check your apache config (/etc/apache2/sites-available/[site_name or default]), it probably contains mod_rewrite instructions, for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

If you comment them out with # and restart apache, accessing /test without specifying extension should no longer work.